# What is the appropriate android sdk version for flutter? Does it include system images?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I installed android sdk from  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip.
I tried setting the path but I keep getting errors. And now the new error is saying Android license status unknown.
Please help, it is now 72 hours I've been working on this error.

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
X Android license status unknown.
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are on Windows? The easiest step would be to download and install Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads

Comment: Android studio eats my RAM for breakfast, lunch, and dinner. I am trying an alternative.

Comment: You don't need to run Android Studio for Flutter development, but installing it for the sdk and using vs code afterwards will work without having RAM issues